# issue: property tasklistviewcontroller not found object type "timertasklistviewcontroller"

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

i have the below issue

property tasklistviewcontroller not found object type "timertasklistviewcontroller".

I cannot access the property one view controller to another view controller. i declare the all class and controller in header. can u help me guys?

Comment: You should post some code so that we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you the truth.  `tasklistviewcontroller` is a property of `TimerAddViewController`, not a property of `TimerTaskListViewControllerViewController`.

Comment: but i set the tasklistviewcontroller in TimerTaskListViewControllerViewController in code

Comment: Look at which class has that @property statement.  According to what you posted, it's in "timeradd.h".

Comment: just i need the tasklistviewcontroller in timeradd.m page.

Comment: That doesn't really matter.  The problem is that you've defined `tasklistviewcontroller` as belonging to one type of object and then you're trying to use it as if it belonged to a different type.  Is `addTaskViewcontroller` really a `TimerTaskListViewControllerViewController` or should it be a `TimerAddViewController`?  (Try `NSLog(@"Controller: %@", addTaskViewcontroller);` and see what that says.)